# How to compare textfield entered amount with total amount in textfield delegate method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I need to compare entered textfield value with totalValue then need to show one error message in red colour

**for that i have tried below code:** here my total amount is 180... i need to show the red coloured text if i enter 181 in textfield but its showing only if i enter 4 characters for eg.. 1811 then its showing but i need immediately after i enter 181 in textfield... where am i wrong? please guide me.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
print(string)
if textField == self.amountTextField {
    if let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        let enteredAmount = textField.text
        let totalAmnt = 180

        if enteredAmount?.toInteger() ?? 0 >= totalAmnt.toInteger(){
            amntErrorLbl.text = "Payment being made is more than quote"
        }
    }
}
return true
}
```

o/p screenshots:

[if i enter 181 in textfield then o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7XG.png)

[if i add 4 numbers then o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6zyA.png)

Comment: Concatenate previous value with current entered value, e.g.
---
`let amount = "\(textField.text ?? "")\(string)"`
`guard let enteredAmount = Int(amount) else { return false }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var totalAmount = 180

func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let text = textField.text,text.isNumbers else {
        return
    }
    guard let enteredAmount = Int(text) else {
        return
    }
    if enteredAmount > totalAmount {
        amntErrorLbl.text = "Entered more than total amount"
    }
    if enteredAmount < totalAmount {
        amntErrorLbl.text = "Entered less than total amount"
    }
    if enteredAmount == totalAmount {
        amntErrorLbl.text = "Entered equal amount"
    }
    
}


extension String {
    var isNumbers:Bool {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return false }
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self).isSubset(of: nums)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, with your code print statement is showing in console but i need to show the text in label.. `if enteredAmount > totalAmount ?? 0 {
            print("entered more than total")
            amntErrorLbl.text = "Payment being made is more than quote"
        } `... the amntErrorLbl.text label not showing if i enter above then total amount

Comment: edited my answer. kindly do some effort its the easiest and fast soltution

Comment: hahaha, actually i have added else block.. with some code thats why i couldn't find text in label